# Is there an AWS API for getting list of all regions?

Tags: amazon-s3, ember.js, aws-regions

currently I am developing a form as below with Ember:

[image: Ember form]

My question is: Is there an API which helps me to fill in this `select` form ? Because I don't want to manually type in the code and then have to change it again if AWS add more regions in the future. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with `aws ec2 describe-regions` (besides that it needs a valid region to operate and technically there may be regions that do not support EC2 thus not listed here)?

Comment: `What's wrong with aws ec2 describe-regions`  That gives regions for the ec2 service;  it says nothing about the s3 service. There is apparently not equivalent for s3. `aws s3 describe-regions` is not supported by aws cli.